# Creating a string with multiple .each functions?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a string that looks similar to this

```
[row]
[column_6]
[element-html]
   MY HTML 
[/element-html]
[/column_6]
[/row]
```

This is generated based on the amount of rows I have then inside the rows the amount of columns, then the amount of elements, here is an HTML example.

```
<div class="row-box">
   <div class="column span6">
   <div class="type-html">MY HTML<input type="hidden" name="html" value="MY HTML"/></div>
   </div>
   <div class="column span6">
   <div class="type-html">MY HTML<input type="hidden" name="html" value="MY HTML"/></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row-box">
   <div class="column span6">
   <div class="type-html">MY HTML<input type="hidden" name="html" value="MY HTML"/></div>
   </div>
   <div class="column span6">
   <div class="type-html">MY HTML<input type="hidden" name="html" value="MY HTML"/></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is some jQuery I wrote

```
$('.row-box').each(function(row) {

    $(this).find('.column').each(function(column) {

        $(this).find('input').each(function(element) {

            var string = $(this).map(function () {
               var $this = $(this).attr("name"),
                   $name = $this.attr("name")

               return '['+row+']['+column+'][element-'+$name+']'+ $this.val() + '[/element-'+$name+'][/column][/row]';

            }).get().join(" ");


        });

    });
});
```

This obviously does not work because it returns a number inside the `['+row+']` and `['+column+']` areas for 1 and it would create that syntax for each element..

I am just not sure how to separate the string so that `[row]` is generated to match each row and inside that row I use `this` to get all columns inside that row, but then again I am not sure how to write a string so that it is separate.

Something like, each row gets this variable `[row]` then each column gets `[column]` then each element `[element-'+$name+']` then combine them, to build one string.

Comment: Not sure I get it, but you should probably read the documentation, the parameters for each are like -> `.each(index, element)`, and right now you're using the index, but using the element wouldn't do much good either, as an element is not a string ?

Comment: Really in this case the index does not mean anything, I understand that. This for each is mainly from another function where i do need the index. regardless I still need to create a `[row]` for each row and so on index or not, its just there because when I viewed it in the console the numbers represented the proper placement, but the string was not proper.. SO my question is how to build a proper string based on each element.

Comment: But why, and with what content, just the strings `row`, `column` etc. ?

Comment: Each row should represent `[row]` then inside that each column should represent `[column]` then inside each column there are elements and they are represented by `[element-'+$name+']` I am trying to build a string so that each row runs the proper nest then inside the row nest is a column nest, then inside that is an element nest. Using each does this nicely, but not sure how to build the string.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9HQu/

Comment: Note that your elements have no name ?

Comment: They do, I just wrote up this example from scratch, thanks for the fiddle the console log shows it perfectly. With the elements and columns I can represent them with proper names.. Looks good post it as an answer and I will check it.. let me fiddle with it.. it returns exactly what I want though

Comment: I did create a variable called `$name` in the OP it gets the input name of the specific element `$this.attr("name")` and the column is a bootstrap grid and the proper span is inside a `data-span` ill pick that up similar to `$this.attr("name")`

Comment: I used this.name in the fiddle above, and it's the same thing, just add names to the inputs

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't really offer anything that @adeneo's demo didn't offer, I had a few moments, and thought I'd post this (albeit as community wiki, since I think it could stand some improvements that I don't, currently, have time to make):

```
var pseudo = $('.row-box').map(function () {
    return '[row] ' + $(this).find('.column').map(function () {
        return '[column] ' + $(this).children().map(function () {
            return '[element-html] ' + $(this).find('input').prop('name') + ' [/element-html]';
        }).get().join(' ') + ' [/column]';
    }).get().join(' ') + ' [/row]';
}).get().join(' ');
console.log(pseudo);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y9HQu/1/).

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).